# Is it possible, in a django template, to check if an object is contained in a list

Tags: django

I'm very new to django, about a week into it.

I'm making a site where users enter stuff, then other users can vote on whether they like the stuff or not. I know it's not so novel, but it's a good project to learn a bunch of tools.

I have a many-to-many table for storing who likes or dislikes what. Before I render the page, I pull out all the likes and dislikes for the current user, along with the stuff I'm going to show on the page.

When I render the page, I go through the list of stuff I'm going to show and print them out one at a time. I want to show the user which stuff they liked, and which they didn't.

So in my django template, I have an object called entry.  I also have two lists of objects called likes and dislikes. Is there any way to determine if entry is a member of either list, inside my django template.

I think what I'm looking for is a filter where I can say something like

```
{% if entry|in:likes %}
```

or

```
{% if likes|contains:entry %}
```

I know I could add a method to my model and check for each entry individually, but that seems like it would be database intensive.

Is there a better way to think about this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go [here](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1350/). Very similar to what they're using on trunk. "Save this as smart_if.py in the templatetags folder of one of your apps. Then a simple {% load smart_if %} replaces the boring built-in Django {% if %} template with the new smart one."

Answer (score 18):

If you're using latest django version, then it's just

```
{% if entry in likes %}
```

[Refer django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#in-operator)

Comment: I'm using 1.1.1. is there any option without upgrading? When is dev going to be production? Does anyone know?

Comment: Some people know. Here's the link from the home page: http://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2010/mar/09/django-1_2-release-schedule/

Answer (score -1):

If you're not running trunk one of the following should work:

[Filter:](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/379/)

Replacement "if" tag, largely the basis for the [new functionality](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1350/) in the upcoming 1.2 release:

Comment: It's recommended tu include the solution here, not only the links to it.