# Django - check if list contains something in a template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I'm trying to check if an item is in a list (set) inside of a template.

I've found this question here:
[Is it possible, in a django template, to check if an object is contained in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427457/is-it-possible-in-a-django-template-to-check-if-an-object-is-contained-in-a-lis)

however the solution isn't working for me.

I'm trying this:

```
{% if trip in request.user.trip_set.all %}
```

where trip is an instance of a Trip,
user is a User,
Trip has a ManyToManyField connecting it to User, through TripReservation

```
class TripReservation(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    trip = models.ForeignKey(Trip)

class Trip(models.Model):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User,blank=True,null=True,through='TripReservation')
```

Comment: What version of Django are you using? That should work in the latest version.

Comment: I'm using Django 1.2.  I think it's because that's a queryset

Answer (score 2):

`request.user.trip_set.all` is not a list but a queryset. I think it is the reason of your problem. You can try to change that into a list with the dictsort template filter.

```
{% if trip in request.user.trip_set.all|dictsort:"id" %}
```

Comment: That didn't work.  I don't think dictsort is for converting querysets to lists.  Is there another way?